# Determining the highest and lowest number

Tags: c++, function

I'm having difficulty creating a void/reference function to determine the highest and lowest number.  The numbers were inputted earlier and assigned to four separate variables.  The numbers will only range from 0 to 100.  I cannot use arrays and it must be a function.  My teacher said he was able to complete with with 6 conditionals and I have closer to 12.

```
void GetGradesFromUser(double& grade1, double& grade2, double& grade3, double& grade4)
{
    cout << "Enter four test grades: ";
    cin >> grade1 >> grade2 >> grade3 >> grade4;
}

double DetermineMaxAndMin(double& grade1, double& grade2, double& grade3, double& grade4)
{
    double max;
    double min;

    if (grade1 >= grade2 && grade1 >= grade3 && grade1 >= grade4)
    {
        max = grade1;
    }

    else if (grade2 >= grade1 && grade2 >= grade3 && grade2 >= grade4)
    {
        max = grade2;
    }

    else if (grade3 >= grade1 && grade3 >= grade2 && grade3 >= grade4)
    {
        max = grade3;
    }

    else max = grade4;

    if (grade1 <= grade2 && grade1 <= grade3 && grade1 <= grade4)
    {
        min = grade1;
    }

    else if (grade2 <= grade1 && grade2 <= grade3 && grade2 <= grade4)
    {
        min = grade2;
    }

    else if (grade3 <= grade1 && grade3 <= grade2 && grade3 <= grade4)
    {
        min = grade3;
    }

    else min = grade4;
}
```

Comment: Try to get it to compile, before optimizing? (pay attention to warnings) Then you only need 4 conditions.

Answer (score -1):

If you can't use arrays and loops, and would like to achieve a result in no more than 6 conditionals, consider the following:

```
double DetermineMaxAndMin(double& grade1, double& grade2, double& grade3, double& grade4)
{
    double max = grade1;
    double min = grade1;

    //find max
    if (max < grade2) max = grade2;
    if (max < grade3) max = grade3;
    if (max < grade4) max = grade4;

    //find min
    if (min > grade2) min = grade2;
    if (min > grade3) min = grade3;
    if (min > grade4) min = grade4;
}
```

The trick is to assume you've already found the max/min, and replace its value when comparing against new values.

Answer (score -2):

int a[101]; int min =0; int max =0;

min = a[0]; max=a[0];

for(int i =0; i < 101; i++){         if (min > a[i]){min=a[i];}; if(max < a[i]){max=a[i];};        };

so if your number are 1 2 3 4;

min = 1; max = 1; min values will be 1 1 1 1; for each iteration; 
                  max values will be 1 2 3 4; for each iteration;

This is an example with arrays daaa. but if you are smart enough, you can apply my approach. you just need to adjust my code and delete array part.

P.s. that code contains 2 conditionals and sorts any amount of numbers. its so basic that you can definately do it.